# Port 80 Occupied

Tags: windows, port, apache-2.4

When trying to run Apache from the Windows Command Line, it gives the error

(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs
Then I used the `netstat -a` command to find anything else that's running on Port 80. CMD reveals that there are to services listening an port 80, but I can't find the source.

**Edit**

I just realized that another instance of Apache was already running on it was listening on port 80... Stopping it worked.

Comment: Did you look at your firewall settings for programs listed to listen on 80?

Comment: What user is it running as?  is it running as a non-privileged user?